# drf yasg how to add new options to response content type

Tags: python-3.x, drf-yasg

I have defined some interfaces when using `drf-swagger`, they need to specify accept parameters in order to return the content correctly.
For example, I will return a file for download. Obviously, the `application/JSON` parameter cannot provide the correct format.
[image: Here is where I want to add the parameters]
I want to be able to add new options to the response content type. There may already be a solution, but I didn't find it ~

Answer (score 1):

To add additional response content type you should take a look at [DRF renderers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/). `drf-yasg` works on top of `drf`, e.g. see [`get_produces()` code](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/17da098940095e3ca7dd2487397814b4195bdd8e/src/drf_yasg/utils.py#L390).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the reponse content type by creating a custom [renderer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) and setting the `renderer_classes` attribute on the view, here's an example implementation:

```
class PDFRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = "application/pdf"
    format = "pdf"
    charset = None
    render_style = "binary"

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data
```